# Tables in Cloud Datastore suddenly gone

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

In our development project, two tables in datastore are suddenly missing.
In the dashboard the summary of the tables are still shown, but there's no way of querying them.

How can I find out how/by whom/why these tables got deleted?
How is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be only two ways of removing the tables from datastore.

1. Running a script which will delete all entries from the table and eventually table is gone.
2. Deleting all the entries manually by using Google Cloud Datastore UI.

If someone has deleted using step 1 then you might be able to track it down by logs but if it has been done using step 2 then I'm sorry there is no way to know who has done it.

Hope this answers your question!!